# Importing libraries in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I'm new to Python, so this question might be easy. But I tried to search on the internet and didn't reach an explanation.

I'm trying to imitate a simple script dealing with xml where it imports the following

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement
```

**Question**: *Why all this?*

Why can't I just say `import xml.etree` and others are just like ancestors. Or even only `import xml`. I've tried this but it's not working. Why?

Comment: You can just `import xml`, but then you would have to write the whole `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` each time you wanted to use that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import  *
```

However, this is bad form since you could have conflicting names from different package imports.  It's always best to specify the exact classes you want and alias them as needed--class name like `Element` one would assume could be very common and you could get collisions.

I'd recommend basically stick your original:

```
  from xml.etree import ElementTree
  from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
```

I think the confusion you're hitting is you have a mix of classes named after files that also have other classes in them.

The first will import the class `ElementTree`, from the file `ElementTree`, this is convention.  The second line will import the classes `Element` and `SubElement` which also happen to be inside the file `ElementTree`.

This will work too and is more succinct:

```
  from xml.etree.ElementTree import  ElementTree, SubElement, Element
```

Comment: Yes, in fact, that's a terrible way is you ask me

Comment: @Ray, thanks for the reply. But still when I do it like this `from xml.etree import  *` I get the following error; `NameError: name 'ElementTree' is not defined`. The error only goes if I make it like this `from xml.etree import ElementTree`

Comment: @KhaledMaged  Have you tried `from xml.etree.ElementTree import *`

Comment: @Ray, now I get it. Danke :)